# Inverse of a vector in a vectorspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $(V,+,\cdot)$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb K$. For a $v\in V$ Let $-v$ be its inverse in $V$ and for $a\in \mathbb K$ let $a’$ be its additive inverse in $\mathbb K$

Now is $-v$ the same as $(1)’\cdot v$? Where the RHS is the vector $v$ scaled by the additive inverse of $1$ in $\mathbb K$. I don’t know how to prove this but we should probably use the identity $1\cdot v=v$.

Comment: Yes, it's one of the basic properties of the vector spaces. You can find it in most Linear Algebra books, some times in the text, some times as an exercise, written in the form $(-1)\cdot v = -v$ (No need to introduce extra notation since the operators are always overloaded in the theory of vector spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We compute
$$
   (1)' \cdot v + v = (1)' \cdot v + 1 \cdot v = ((1)' + 1) \cdot v = 0 \cdot v = 0
$$
using that $1 \cdot v = v$, $(a + b) \cdot v = a \cdot v + b \cdot v$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{K}$, and $0 \cdot v = 0$, so the answer to your questions is "yes."